# Identifying the second parameter type when it depends on the first parameter type in the function's implementation

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have 2 types of messages and different context for each.

I've created a function which takes `type` and `context` and is able to tell the caller of the function which `context` to use based on the `type`

```js
const MessageOptions = {
  textMessage: "textMessage",
  interactiveFormMessage: "interactiveFormMessage"
} as const;

type MessageOptions = typeof MessageOptions[keyof typeof MessageOptions];

interface SimpleTextMessageContext { ... }

interface InteractiveFormMessageContext { ... }


interface MessageTypes {
  textMessage: SimpleTextMessageContext;
  interactiveFormMessage: InteractiveFormMessageContext;
};

function sendInteractiveMessage<T extends MessageOptions>(
  type: T,
  details: MessageTypes[T]
) { ... }

sendInteractiveMessage(MessageOptions.textMessage, /* expects text message context */{});
sendInteractiveMessage(MessageOptions.interactiveFormMessage, /* expects form context */{});
```

The problem I'm having is that inside the implementation of `sendInteractiveMessage` I cannot refer to `details` as the right context w/o `details as SimpleTextMessageContext`. see example:

```js
function sendInteractiveMessage<T extends MessageOptions>(
  type: T,
  details: MessageTypes[T]
) {
  if (type === MessageOptions.textMessage) {
    details // type here is MessageOptions[T] and NOT SimpleTextMessageContext
    // ^?
  }
}
```

Is there a way to effect `details`'s type **in the implementation** based on `type`'s type?

Thank you!

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-TLA268OQKMNZafMjtLQACwQVSqIBgAHcVFVEVxzJ7ciXFbNlQgK1XLhAI2MOQKjOEEA2tjsONwICBVB58PRhC9ztBMpxos9XtxinIVNsPKAO5J9ygT1xJAh+58uC42x2u-uuAAjKpzi4LJgSydFkChTgyEsQcxSoIA)

Comment: If you use a mapped type to generate a union of the possible arguments, TypeScript will be able to infer and narrow the type of `details` based on the type of `type`: https://tsplay.dev/N7ynEW. Generics aren't really suitable for functions where the return type depends on the parameters. As an example, consider the case when I call yours as `sendInteractiveMessage<MessageOptions>(...)`. Then what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @caTS, that solution of tying both together (in a object or a tuple in your case) doesn't work for the caller. In your case, the caller will now have a union off all message types in the context

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean since if you call them with incorrect arguments it'll give you an error: https://tsplay.dev/w8LOAw

Comment: correct, the issue i was referring to is that if you `ctrl+space` (or `command+space` on mac) on `details`, you'll see all 4 options (text, title, questions, and assests). once you try to implement it it will error, but i wanted ts intellisense to "understand" what type it is.

Comment: @caTS, even with my previous comment, your answer is a valid solution and I'd be happy to mark the question as solved. If you don't mind, would you post it as an answer so I can checkmark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same behavior as before while having the types being narrowed by creating a union of the possible arguments to your function:

```
type Args = {
  [K in MessageOptions]: [type: K, details: MessageTypes[K]];
}[MessageOptions]

function sendInteractiveMessage(...[type, details]: Args) {
  if (type === MessageOptions.textMessage) {
    details
  }
}
```

You'll notice that autocomplete now gives you fields of both types for the `details` parameter, which is understandably annoying. You can opt-in to use an external signature (which is just your original functions') so userland is happy and you're happy with the function body as well:

```
type Args = {
  [K in MessageOptions]: [type: K, details: MessageTypes[K]];
}[MessageOptions]

// extra signature so userland doesn't get excess invalid properties
function sendInteractiveMessage<K extends MessageOptions>(type: K, details: MessageTypes[K]): void;
function sendInteractiveMessage(...[type, details]: Args) {
  if (type === MessageOptions.textMessage) {
    details
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqkDkw)